# How do I set session timeout in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.x and I want to know how do I set session time out to 8hrs. Please note that session should not expire before 8hrs. I have used

```
Configure::write('Session.timeout', '480');
```

but session still expires after few minutes.

Can anyone tell how do I set session time out to 8hrs, so that it will expire exactly after 8hrs?

Comment: Read [the bottom part here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2012/02/02/more-persistent-sessions-in-cake2-x/) about the importance of the cookie timeout value in order to actually have an 8 hour session regardless of your session timeout value. Note that that cookie timeout is fixed and therefore needs to be set quite high.

Answer (score 0):

Reset the session cookie expiration date:
`$this->Session->renew()`.

UPD: you can also do that by:

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
        'timeout' => '480',
        'autoRegenerate' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: It will only reset the session id, but how do I set session time out exactly to 8hrs?

Comment: Can you set session.cookie_lifetime var?